# How to eliminate black bars?

Tags: jwplayer

I am using JWPlayer 6.3 to embed videos in an HTML/Javascript application.
I have an outer div that holds the container div into which the video is
embedded.  The container is centered in both directions within the outer div.
The outer div dimensions are roughly those of the browser window.
I'm calling jwplayer("container").setup({options}) to embed the video.
All good.

The app shows different videos at different times by calling
jwplayer("container").setup({options}) again with a different video.
I want to have each video fill the outer div as best it can, while still
keeping its own aspect ratio.  The video aspect ratio is guaranteed to
be different than that of the outer div at any given time.

If I choose stretching: "bestfit", I'll get the Dreaded Black Bars (™).
This would be fine if I could also choose a color for these bars
(I would choose white).

```
Q1: can I/how do I specify the color of the bars?
```

If I could detect the size of the video at run time, I could then specify
a width and height for the embed (via .setup()) with the she aspect ratio,
and use stretching: "exactfit".

```
Q2: can I/how can I detect the size of the video at run time?
```

thanks
Fred Ross-Perry

Answer (score 0):

You should use exactfit, not bestfit. If that doesn't work, try fill. You can probably use our API, and getMeta() to detect the size of the video - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference